# How to probably handle websocket call back in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

This is my first time dealing with web sockets

I have a `websocket` connection using `okhttp` inside a `WebSocketManager` class

I also have a listener that extends `WebSocketListener` that is passed to this connection for call backs,
this websocket listener overrides few methods one of them is

```
override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {}
```

What is the proper way to share this data from the manager class with the compose screen?

what I did was that inside this manager class (which I made a singleton) I have a shared flow

```
private val _socketEvents = MutableSharedFlow<WebSocketEvent>()
val socketEvents:SharedFlow<WebSocketEvent> get() = _socketEvents
```

What I am doing is that I am passing the ViewModel scope of that screen to the manager class and then I use this scope to emit values through the `_socketEvents` shared flow.

```
override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
       externalScope.launch {
       val result = convertStringToModel(text)
       _socketEvents.emit(WebSocketEvent.OnMessageReceived(result))
   }
 }
```

then I am collecting from this Shared flow inside my view model and presenting data on the screen.

does this make sense?

Manager class constructor looks like this:

```
class WebSocketManager private constructor(
    private val externalScope: CoroutineScope
)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am trying to implement the same.